# 'Unexpected token <' when wrapping .vue file in <template>

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

new to vue here and I am creating an area in the code for all my vue components to be rendered through a `blade.php` file (sfc).
I installed the cli using `vue create projectName` and linked the file but it seems the  tag is causing an issue.

Doesnt Vue need to be wrapped within the template?
let me know if theres any more information needed.

Blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

<script src="/projectName/src/App.vue"></script>


@endsection
```

App.vue

```
<template id="myStuff">
  <div>omg it works?</div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
new Vue({
    el: "#myStuff"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Browser cannot transpile (or whatever term to use) vue files. You need to build it first `npm run build`. See package.json for other scripts. And then in dist folder are your ready for browser files.

Comment: ahhh yes! the dist will be the compiled version. duh! thank you! I also found during the process this will throw an error if youre not exporting the component.